# no matching function for call to ‘std::set<unsigned int>::insert(std::size_t&)

Tags: c++, pcl

I am working on migrating my package from ros melodic to ros noetic. while doing it I got compilation error in PCL library during cmake. The package is too big I am giving some code where error happened. Any guidance would be helpfull.
This is myfile.cpp

```
std::vector<bool> ignore_labels;

ignore_labels.resize(2);
ignore_labels[0] = true;
ignore_labels[1] = false;

//TODO commented that out i think we have to fix the error
ecc->setExcludeLabels(ignore_labels);
```

'''

and this is the PCL-1.10 library file it called at line **ecc->setExcludeLabels(ignore_labels);** here error occured,

'''
brief Set labels in the label cloud to exclude.
param[in] exclude_labels a vector of bools corresponding to whether or not a given label should be considered

```
  void
  setExcludeLabels (const std::vector<bool>& exclude_labels)
  {
    exclude_labels_ = boost::make_shared<std::set<std::uint32_t> > ();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < exclude_labels.size (); ++i)
      if (exclude_labels[i])
        exclude_labels_->insert (i);
  }
```

'''

the error is

**/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/segmentation/euclidean_cluster_comparator.h:256:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set::insert(std::size_t&) const’
256 |             exclude_labels_->insert (i);
|             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/9/set:61,**

Comment: What is the type of `exclude_labels_`?

Comment: exclude_labels_ is of type std::set<std::uint32_t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked into the source code for this library, here is the issue:

[image]

The type is a typedef:
[image]

The issue is that the object itself is a `shared_ptr<const std::set<std::uint32_t>>`
the code you have posted is allocating the object, but also calling `std::set::insert` on an instance of `const std::set`, which does not exist because by `std::set::insert` modifies the state of the `std::set`

notice the const at the end of the compiler error: `‘std::set::insert(std::size_t&) const`
it means you are trying to call a version of `insert` that is `const`, which does not exist (and cannot exist)

[Here you can learn more about const-qualified methods](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-member-functions-c/)

Comment: It is a third-party library so I cant do anything of it also the PCL version for 1.8 also has these statements above but there it works fine. The problem is something else?

Answer (score -1):

You cannot add an element of type `size_t` (usually `UInt64`) to `set<UInt32>` because you cannot compare `UInt64` and `UInt32`.

Answer (score -1):

The error occurs because a variable of `size_t` is tried to insert in the container `exclude_labels_`. Please cast the variable `i` to `uint32_t` and then try to insert in the container `exclude_labels_`.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but as you said the error in the exclude_labels_ code which is of PCL1-10 library whihc should not be wrong, right? I will try to cast and the ask if it work

Comment: The error remains after static casting.

**/usr/include/pcl-1.10/pcl/segmentation/euclidean_cluster_comparator.h:256:13: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<unsigned int>::insert(pcl::uint32_t) const’
  256 |             exclude_labels_->insert (static_cast<uint32_t>(i));**

Comment: size_t could end up being 64 bit, sure, but it isn't a compiler error, it will only end up having loss of precision at best as it will get up catting implicitly downcasted to 32-bit

Comment: But it is not linking and cmake is not compiled?